# How to get symbol layer on paperjs?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

This code draws 30 led image to canvas.How can i select and change  source  of  led symbol onMouseDown event?

```
var raster = new Raster();
raster.source="/PNG/Red.png";
var sembol = new Symbol(raster);

for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var bura = sembol.place();
    bura.position = Point.random() * view.size;
    bura.scale(0.5);


};
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a set of raster objects in your view, like a row of buttons, the following should work:

```
function onMouseDown(event) {
    if (event.item && event.item.type === 'raster') {
            sembol.definition = event.item.clone();
    }
}
```

Since an item is removed from the view when defined as a symbol, a clone is passed instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [onMouseDown handler](http://paperjs.org/reference/placedsymbol/#onmousedown) directly to a `PlacedSymbol`, in this case `bura`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  var bura = sembol.place();
  bura.position = Point.random() * view.size;
  bura.scale(0.5);

  bura.onMouseDown = function () {        
    // you can use the closure variable `raster`
    raster.source = "/PNG/Blue.png";

    // or, if you don't have acces to `raster`:
    this.symbol.definition.source = "/PNG/Blue.png";
  }
}
```

Hope that this does what you expected.